# Error while compiling substrate recipes

Tags: substrate-recipes

While compiling substrate recipes, I encounter the following error (error message copied below as well as the screenshot is attached.

```
error: duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `serde` depends on): `panic_impl`.
= note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `ocw_demo` depends on)
= note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/kamran/Substrate/recipes/target/debug/wbuild/ocw-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-ebd74ffdd043ce0a.rmeta

= note: second definition in `std` loaded from /home/kamran/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-a237209e92b55a70.rlib


error: duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `serde` depends on): `oom`.
= note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `ocw_demo` depends on)
= note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/kamran/Substrate/recipes/target/debug/wbuild/ocw-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-ebd74ffdd043ce0a.rmeta

= note: second definition in `std` loaded from /home/kamran/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-a237209e92b55a70.rlib 

error: could not compile `ocw-demo` due to 2 previous errors
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error is with the **serde** dependency.

```
error: duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `serde` depends on)
```

This is a dependency that does have no-std support but can have std enabled by default.

To fix it add `default-features = false`, in the Cargo.toml in the runtime:

```
serde = { version = '1.0', optional = true, default-features = false, features = ['derive'] }
```